# Stored procedure returns different values in C# vs. SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure (sql server 2012) with parameter `@id int OUTPUT`
The procedure inserts to the database`s table some data and returns the ID of the affected row

```
SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN @id
```

I test it from SQL Server and it works fine. But when I call it from C# : it indeed inserts the data to the table,but returns null:

```
SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
parm.Size = 32;
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // This is important!
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
object id = (int?)cmd.ExecuteScalar();//<-null
```

Please point me out what causes this strange behavior?

Comment: @Steve  - sorry - it is a typo

Comment: Please see my comments on the answers from both Steve and Damith. In short, please do _not_ use RETURN for getting an IDENTITY value as the datatype for RETURN is only INT while IDENTITY can be BIGINT, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value for the ID is stored in the Output parameter that can be read after the execution of the query.

```
SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
parm.Size = 32;
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // This is important!
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
object id = (int)cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value;
```

Or you could change the query itself to have as last line the

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And get the value from the ExecuteScalar  (no need to pass an ID parameter in this case)

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null) 
    id = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Comment: +1 due to using an OUTPUT param being the far better choice for getting SCOPE_IDENTITY(), which returns NUMERIC(38,0) and works with IDENTITY fields that are BIGINT, NUMERIC/DECIMAL, etc. A return value is only INT.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the return value as

```
 parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 var id = (int?)parm.Value;
```

Comment: what is a diff between Output and ReturnValue directions?

Comment: since you using `return @id` you have to use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` but you can use `select @id` for `ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: What you said raises an exception parameter @id is not supplied

Comment: @Yakov need to add parm to cmd

Comment: While this does show the correct syntax for getting a return value (which is good and technically answers the question as asked), it is a bad practice to use a return value for getting an IDENTITY value. An IDENTITY field can be INT, BIGINT, NUMERIC/DECIMAL, etc but a return value will only ever be INT. Please use an OUTPUT param, or even the SELECT via ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.Int);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmdHeader.Parameters.Add(param);

    //   Execute your command
cmdHeader.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //   Get the return value
int returnvalue = (int)myCommand.Parameters["id"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Key part is in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query

I.e. ExecuteScalar doesn't return the return value.  If you want to get the value this way, select the value in your query:

```
SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT @id
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Of course, that's not going to be any good if your query already returns a result set.

If you really want the return value, you need to use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` not `ParameterDirection.Output` then read it as a parameter value:

```
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
int id = (int)cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value;
```